# Zend Validate set number default

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-validate

Whats up?! by example, my name validate when minimun and maximun caracteres..... min 3 and max 25. i do this:

$name = new Zend_Validate_StringLength();
$name->setMin(3);
$name->setMax(25);

i have a class, and the number for validate is a number exactly, by example my year, are four numbers every. I know do this action:

$name = new Zend_Validate_StringLength();
$name->setMin(4);
$name->setMax(4);

how i can valid without say min equal to max ????

Comment: Are you saying you don't want to set the min and the max, you just want to say something like, setLength(4)?

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  If you set only the max, then there is no restriction on the min.  If you set only the min, there is no restriction on the max.  In order to validate that your string is exactly 4 characters you must set both the min and the max, or you can [write your own validator](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.writing_validators.html).

Since you are validating a year, you may also want to add the Zend_Validate_Digits validator.

Answer (score 0):

As Jody mentioned, you are required to set both a minimum and maximum. If all your trying to avoid is the usage of multiple setters, use the constructor arguments.

```
public function __construct($min = 0, $max = null, $encoding = null)
```